# Simulating data for a Cox model using coxed package

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate survival data in order to run a Cox model. I want to show that the estimated coefficients are close to the true values. However, when I run my code the true values do not lie in the 95% confidence interval as often as expected (only 34% of the time). Is there an error in my code? Can anyone explain why the estimates are not as close to the true value as we would expect?

```
library(MASS)
library(survival)
library(coxed)
library(survminer)

set.seed(0)

num_sims <- 100
sim_estimates <- matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = num_sims)
colnames(sim_estimates) <- c("Estimate", "2.5%", "97.5%")

for (sim_number in 1:num_sims) {
    sim_data <- sim.survdata(N=1000, T=100, xvars=2, censor =0.1, 
    num.data.frames=1, beta = c(-0.5, 0.5))
    sim_model <- coxph(Surv(y, failed) ~ X1 + X2, data=sim_data$data)
    sim_estimates[sim_number,1] <- sim_model$coefficients[1]
    sim_estimates[sim_number,2] <- confint(sim_model)[1,1]
    sim_estimates[sim_number,3] <- confint(sim_model)[1,2]
}

sum (-0.5 >= sim_estimates[,2] & -0.5 <= sim_estimates[,3])
```

Comment: I ran your code and I got 92%.

Comment: The exact code? How is it possible that we would get different results whilst including a seed? I have run it numerous times and alway get the same results. Thanks, Erin